# lm() datframes and for-loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, lm

I have dataframe `DFMyDataBase` :

```
DATE          AUDCAD      AUDCHF       AUDJPY     AUDNZD      (...)
05/01/2017  0.965960    0.742230    85.315000   1.048500      (...)
08/01/2017  0.971760    0.746410    85.353000   1.048140      (...)
09/01/2017  0.975070    0.749300    85.307000   1.054290      (...)
10/01/2017  0.980720    0.754540    85.873000   1.054380      (...)
11/01/2017  0.983750    0.756540    85.861000   1.053650      (...)
12/01/2017  0.983320    0.756070    85.822000   1.051750      (...)
(...)
```

And dataframe `DFLM`:

```
FirstSymbol     SecondSymbol    PValue     DickeyFullerCV
     AUDCAD           AUDCHF
     AUDCAD           AUDJPY
     AUDCAD           AUDNZD
     AUDCAD           AUDUSD
      (...)            (...)
```

build lm() based on the pairs of names stored in `DFLM`, which represent the column names in `DFMyDataBase`. The first column of `DFLM` represent the dependent variable and the second column the independent variable.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do.  Please clarify the question. Also read the posting instructions at the top of the [tag:r]  tag page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you wish to build formulas based on the pairs of names stored in `DFLM`, which represent the column names in `DFMyDataBase`, then use these formulae as the basis for running `lm` on each pair. I am further guessing that you want the first column of `DFLM`to represent the dependent variable and the second column to be the independent variable.

That being the case, you could do something like

```r
f_list <- apply(DFLM, 1, function(x) as.formula(paste(x[1], "~", x[2])))

models <- lapply(f_list, function(x) {
  eval(call("lm", formula = x, data = quote(DFMyDataBase)))
  })
```

So now `models` is a list of `lm` objects, one for each row of `DFLM`, allowing you to do:

```r
models[[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = AUDCAD ~ AUDCHF, data = DFMyDataBase)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)       AUDCHF  
#>     0.06269      1.21739
```

or

```r
summary(models[[3]])
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = AUDCHF ~ AUDNZD, data = DFMyDataBase)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#>          1          2          3          4          5          6 
#> -0.0037091  0.0010088 -0.0052919 -0.0001864  0.0029046  0.0052740 
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
#> (Intercept)  -0.8210     0.7342  -1.118    0.326  
#> AUDNZD        1.4944     0.6980   2.141    0.099 .
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Residual standard error: 0.004446 on 4 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:  0.534,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.4175 
#> F-statistic: 4.583 on 1 and 4 DF,  p-value: 0.09899
```

and so on.

Note that in your sample data frame your fourth row contains the same column name twice - it's not clear what you intend for this type of situation. I have altered the input a bit as shown below.

---

**Data**

```r
DFMyDataBase <- structure(list(DATE = c("05/01/2017", "08/01/2017",
"09/01/2017", "10/01/2017", "11/01/2017", "12/01/2017"), AUDCAD = c(0.96596, 
0.97176, 0.97507, 0.98072, 0.98375, 0.98332), AUDCHF = c(0.74223, 
0.74641, 0.7493, 0.75454, 0.75654, 0.75607), AUDJPY = c(85.315, 
85.353, 85.307, 85.873, 85.861, 85.822), AUDNZD = c(1.0485, 1.04814, 
1.05429, 1.05438, 1.05365, 1.05175)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

DFLM <- structure(list(FirstSymbol = c("AUDCAD", "AUDCAD", "AUDCHF"), 
    SecondSymbol = c("AUDCHF", "AUDJPY", "AUDNZD")), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")

DFMyDataBase
#>         DATE  AUDCAD  AUDCHF AUDJPY  AUDNZD
#> 1 05/01/2017 0.96596 0.74223 85.315 1.04850
#> 2 08/01/2017 0.97176 0.74641 85.353 1.04814
#> 3 09/01/2017 0.97507 0.74930 85.307 1.05429
#> 4 10/01/2017 0.98072 0.75454 85.873 1.05438
#> 5 11/01/2017 0.98375 0.75654 85.861 1.05365
#> 6 12/01/2017 0.98332 0.75607 85.822 1.05175

DFLM
#>   FirstSymbol SecondSymbol
#> 1      AUDCAD       AUDCHF
#> 2      AUDCAD       AUDJPY
#> 3      AUDCHF       AUDNZD
```

Comment: Why `eval` and not just pass formula into `lm`? Also, consider `reformulate` over `as.formula` + `paste`.

Comment: @Parfait if you pass the formula directly it still kinda works, except the "call" member of the `lm` object is wrong because the formula is captured by NSE.

Comment: Again, not sure why you need `eval` or `call`. Works great without: https://rextester.com/DKQ52048

Comment: @Parfait when I run that code on Rextester, each list item is printed showing the Call and the Coefficients for each model, but the Call is `lm(formula = x, data = DFMyDataBase)` for each of them, rather than e.g.  `lm(formula = AUDCHF ~ AUDNZD, data = DFMyDataBase)` If you run it with my `eval` version you get the actual column names in the formula as you would if you wrote it by hand, as in my example. In many cases this isn't a deal breaker, but to me it's preferable to see the variables being regressed in the call rather than the unsubstituted `formula = x`

Comment: Understood, now! Thanks! I shy away from `eval` but it has its use cases.

Comment: @Parfait I do try to avoid `eval` and don't think I'd ever offer an answer here that used `eval(parse(...))`, but there are the odd exceptions to using `eval` (like when you have an NSE function inside an *apply). Thanks for the `reformulate` tip - I'm always learning on SO.